# No value specified for parameter 1 - is the query too long?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, jooq

I am running a simple insert using jooq:

```
InsertValuesStep6<...>
    insertInto =
        withContext()
            .insertInto(
                MyTable,
                MyTable.ID);
for (Integer id : ids) {
  insertInto = insertInto.values(id);
}

insertInto.execute();
```

I simplified it a bit for the question, there are couple of more fields in each row.

It usually works fine, but once in a while get an exception: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.`

So I suspect it's not a syntax issue but scale issue.
Maybe the actual query is trimmed by jooq somehow?

Comment: Are you sure nothing got lost in your simplification? You mention `InsertValuesStep6` (i.e. 6), but only pass 1 column to the `insertInto()` clause. Also, `MyTable` is a bit unusual as a table reference, at least for out-of-the-box code generator configurations. Can you please post an example that matches your *actual* query exactly, or at least reduce it correctly to a minimal example that still compiles, and reproduces the issue? Otherwise, we might be chasing reduction artifacts, not your actual issue.

Comment: For the record, if you think this is a bug, you can try to create an MCVE (Minimal, Commplete, Verifiable Example) using this template: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Comment: From your comments I understand I might be running into a bug. I will try to reproduce it.